# Sitecore admin folder anonymous access restrictions

Tags: authentication, sitecore, sitecore6

[Sitecore security hardening guide](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Reference/Sitecore%206/Security%20Hardening%20Guide.aspx) instructs to restrict access to /sitecore/admin folder by disabling **anonymous** access. However, after I do that, I get an IIS error when I try to visit pages like /sitecore/admin/cache.aspx.

HTTP Error 401.2 - Unauthorized. You are not authorized to view this page due to invalid authentication headers.

Should anonymous access only be disabled if I don't want to access admin pages?

My sitecore version is 6.6.0 (rev. 130404).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to disabling anonymous access, you should make sure some sort of other authentication method *is* enabled. By default, IIS7+ doesn't have any other authentication methods available, so all traffic will get an "unauthorized" error. With another means of authentication enabled, IIS will let you access the /sitecore/admin path (at which point, Sitecore's authentication may kick in).

I've done this in the past by creating a local user on the machine and enabling basic auth. Keep in mind, basic auth is not too secure since credentials are passed over the wire as cleartext, but in this case we forced traffic over SSL.

Though not spelled out in the hardening guide, you could also look at limiting access to that directory by IP address. For example, on a production content delivery server, restrict access to only localhost, meaning you cannot browse that directory without being RDP'd to the server directly.

Comment: It seems that I have to address this as a website-specific security scenario. Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should remove extranet/anonymous access, but make sure that sitecore/everybody (or other role) has access.

That way you can only access it while logged into Sitecore.

Use the Access Viewer to check that users have access to it.

And I think that those pages, have a Sitecore login now. I know /sitecore/admin/dbbrowser.aspx has one.

Comment: Sitecore security hardening guide does not talk about sitecore roles. It instructs to restrict anonymous access using IIS [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17828974/iis-7-how-to-preserve-website-subfolder-authentication-settigns/17843078?noredirect=1#comment26106196_17843078). After I do that, I don't even get the sitecore admin login page. That's the problem I'm facing. Even the access to /sitecore/admin/login.aspx page is also disabled by IIS.

Comment: Sitecore security hardening guide doesn't because since version 6.2 100507 and up it's restricted to anonymous users anyway. A login page will be shown when an anonymous user tries to access one of those pages. You can restrict the Sitecore folder in your production environment, allowing only certain ip's to request those pages in case you want to harden the security.

Comment: Ok, thought about the IIS anonymous access, but didn't think that would be it. As @Younes says, access to those pages are retrcited now anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I would not disable the anonymous access unless it is the production environment. I am not sure how you have the environments setup but ideally cache clearance should be on your stage/uat environment.

Comment: I don't think the environment matters here. Sitecore admin utilities might be needed in dev end prod environments both. I'm took cache.aspx as an example. There are more admin utilities which is helpful in a production environment. So I want to have access to admin pages while restricting anonymous access.